# Are the phrases "jarabe para la tos" or "antibióticos" colloquially used to mean other types of medicine?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

My spanish textbook says that if you have a fever, you should take "jarabe para la tos". It also recommends "antibióticos" as a remedy for "la gripe". The glossary translates these phrases as "cough syrup", "antibiotics", and "flu" respectively.

While a language textbook isn't obligated to contain scientifically accurate advice, this is plain wrong. I talked to my teacher (grew up in the US but spoke only spanish at home), and she said she always took antibiotics for the flu. I also have some Filipino friends that believe antibiotics help the flu.

Are these phrases used to mean both antibiotics and antiviral drugs? Is this a common misconception among spanish and spanish-influenced speakers?

Comment: Joke ahead don't take it seriously: I think you are looking for the world "tequila". http://bit.ly/1au8w0v

Comment: Where you said "el gripe" should be "la gripe"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your book is right. The belief that antibiotics help cure viral infections is a common misunderstanding in many parts of the world, not just Spanish-speaking countries. It has nothing to do with the language.

Comment: Yeah, most people don't know the difference between antibiotics and antivirals.

Answer (score 4):

The glossary of your book is correct.

> la gripe *means* the flu
>   antibiotics *means* antibióticos
>   jarabe *means* syrup
>   jarabe para la tos  *means*  cough syrup

Moreover

> antivirales *is the translation of* antiviral drugs.

That's the language part of the question. (Maybe if you take another book to learn another language you will find the same "scientific inaccuracy", which not being proper of Spanish, would lead to an off-topic discussion here.)

Answer (score 0):

[Antibiotics](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/antibiotics.html) are actually contraindicated for a common flu.

The common translation for [Syrup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syrup) is `Jarabe`

At least in my country Cuba we use `Jarabe` as  regular rule to treat the flu.

A common say in my country is "Toma un poco de miel con ron para ese catarro"

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed they are specifically used to denote that: cough medicine and antibiotics.  No other mean.  Just that.

Comment: could you specify what countries?

Comment: In whole latin america.  Don't know if Spain at all.

Comment: well in Cuba we know the antibiotic could may more harm than good for a flu